# SmartThreadPool - How to queue an WorkItem in a specific Thread?

Tags: c#

I'm working with the [SmartThreadPool Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool) and I need to do this:

I'm using 10 `Worker Threads` and I need to know what `WorkItem` went to what `Worker Thread`, for after in specific conditions I need to throw another `WorkItem` in the same `Worker Thread`.

Is possible to do it?

Comment: Why not simply queue the two items as one instead?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Imagine that I have a lot of process, each process has a 'random value', so the first process with 'random value' `1` was queued in the first `worker thread`, but it takes about 5 minutes to be processed.
After this, I created a new process with the 'random value' `3`, and it was queued in the second `worker thread`. 
Now, I have two `worker threads` each one with one process. And now, I create a new process and its 'random value' is `1` again, I need to know if have some `worker thread` processing one process with the same 'random value' and if is true queue in the same thread

Comment: @OP: After reading your comment, I still do not understand why you think you need to queue to the same thread.

Comment: @Polyfun Because if a process is in processing on a specific `Worker thread` and one new process is created with the same attributes, it needs to be processed in the same `worker thread`. It's dependency of a business rule of my software, very complex to explain.

Comment: Then you need to write this thread pool yourself. The smart thread pool you link to does not have the facilities to handle this. You throw an item into the bag, it gets picked up by an existing, or new, thread from the pool. If you want more control than that you're going to have to write this yourself.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This answer was already expected, even still I tried to come here, what if it works? haha Thank you.